# DBM::Deep is failing to import hashref having 'true' or 'false' values

Tags: json, perl, hash, decode, dbm

I have the `JSON` text as given below :

### test.json

```
{
  "a" : false
}
```

I want to create the `DBM::Deep` hash for above JSON. My code is looks like as given below :

### dbm.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBM::Deep;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

# create the dbm::deep object
my $db = DBM::Deep->new(
    file => 'test.db',
    type => DBM::Deep->TYPE_HASH
);

my $json_text = do {
    open( my $json_fh, $path )
      or die("Can't open \$path\": $!\n");
    local $/;
    <$json_fh>;
};

my $json = JSON->new;
my $data = $json->decode($json_text);
print Dumper($data);

# create dbm::deep hash
eval { $db->{$path} = $data; };

if ($@) {
    print "error : $@\n";
}
```

I am getting below output/error on execution of above code:

### Error

> $VAR1 = {
>                 'a' => bless( do{(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::XS::Boolean' )
>               };
>       error : DBM::Deep: Storage of references of type 'SCALAR' is not supported. at dbm.pl line 26

It seems like, JSON internally uses JSON::XS which convert the 'true' value in JSON::XS::Boolean object and DBM::Deep is not able to handle this, while it can handle the null value.

While the above code is working fine for below inputs:

```
{
  "a" : 'true'  # if true is in quotes
}
```

or

```
{
  "a" : null 
}
```

I tried many thing, but nothing worked. Does anyone has any workaround?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just store the raw JSON instead of using DBM::Deep?

Comment: My requirement is to store the json structure(upto 4-5 level deep) in some in-memory database, so that i can access them after storing.

Comment: By default, DBM::Deep stores data in a file, not an in-memory database. Can you explain your requirements a little more clearly? I still don't understand why you don't just deserialize the raw JSON file every time you want to use it.

Comment: My Bad : I want to store the data in persistent memory, which can be file also. Hence i chose to DBM::Deep.

Comment: A JSON file *is* persistent.

Comment: Yes, it is persistent.

Comment: So why not just use the JSON file? DBM::Deep just adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I want to map each JSON file content to some key, so that i can access the values as per my requirement.

Comment: You can do that using a simple hash where the values are file names. If the mapping needs to be persistent, you can store it in a file e.g. in CSV format. My point is that JSON is already serialized data; it doesn't make a lot of sense to deserialize it and then serialize it again with DBM::Deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON parser you are using, among others, returns an object that works as a boolean when it encounters `true` or `false` in the JSON. This allows the data to be re-encoded into JSON without change, but it can cause this kind of issue.

`null` doesn't have this problem because Perl has a native value (`undef`) that can be used to represent it unambiguously.

The following convert these objects into simple values.

```
 sub convert_json_bools {
    local *_convert_json_bools = sub {
        my $ref_type = ref($_[0])
            or return;

        if ($ref_type eq 'HASH') {
            _convert_json_bools($_) for values(%{ $_[0] });
        }
        elsif ($ref_type eq 'ARRAY') {
            _convert_json_bools($_) for @{ $_[0] };
        }
        elsif ($ref_type =~ /::Boolean\z/) {
            $_[0] = $_[0] ? 1 : 0;
        }
        else {
            warn("Unsupported type $ref_type\n");
        }
    };

    &_convert_json_bools;
}

convert_json_bools($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i am having deep JSON structure(upto 3-4 level) and having 1000+ json files to create the DBM deep hash, so parsing hash will be quite costly operation.

Comment: 1. What's your point? 2. I don't see why you think this. It can't be more expensive than generating the structure in the first place. 3. The time it takes pales in comparison to the time DBM::Deep takes.

Comment: Yes, i agree with on 3rd point as i bench-marked the above code and it quite lesser than DBM::Deep operation. I had many JSON files and thought to perform above conversion(which is implemented as a recursion call) may take higher time, But now my doubt is clear. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

Your code works fine for me, with the only change being to set

```
my $path = 'test.json';
```

You should check your module version numbers. These are the ones that I have

```
print $DBM::Deep::VERSION, "\n";    # 2.0013
print $JSON::VERSION, "\n";         # 2.90
print $JSON::XS::VERSION, "\n";     # 3.02
```

and I am running Perl v5.24.0

The dumped output is as follows

#### Newly-created `DBM::Deep` database

```
$VAR1 = bless( {}, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' );
```

#### output of `$json->decode`

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => undef
        };
```

#### Populated `DBM::Deep` database after the `eval`

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'test.json' => bless( {
                                         'a' => undef
                                       }, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' )
               }, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' );
```

All of that looks to be as it should

Comment: I think the OP meant to write `false` instead of `null`; JSON `null` is mapped to Perl `undef`, but JSON `false` is mapped to a JSON::PP::Boolean (or similar) object.

Comment: The OP also said it works for `null` further in his answer. It's `false` and `true` that don't work. Fixed question.